# Computing skewness and kurtosis in stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I will like to know how to compute **skewness** and **kurtosis** statistics in `stargazer`. The built in functions per the documentation does not include the above two descriptive statistics. I would be very glad to know if there is a means by which I could get these two statistics included in my descriptive table using `stargazer`.

Thanks for your thoughtful consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need the package `moments`, which contains the functions `skewness()` and `kurtosis()`.

```
library(moments)
v <- c(19.09, 19.55, 17.89, 17.73, 25.15)
> skewness(v)
[1] 1.265122

> kurtosis(v)
[1] 2.93613
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But what I seek actually to do is to add the skewness and kurtosis statistics to the descriptive table generated by stargazer as one table, like those created for  regression models. But when I do that I get the error message **! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.**